# Memcached is not working as expected, unable to retrieve value (Docker / Memcached / Windows)

Tags: windows, docker, memcached

I'm running memcached using docker on my windows.

I have been trying to get memcached working with python, but the value is not getting stored in memcache. Output is included below in BOLD.

```
    import memcache
    client = memcache.Client([('127.0.0.1', 11211)])
    sample_obj = {"name": "Soliman","lang": "Python"}
    client.set("sample_user", sample_obj, time=15)
    print("Stored to memcached, will auto-expire after 15 seconds")
    print(client.get("sample_user"))
```

**Stored to memcached, will auto-expire after 15 seconds**

**None**

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php returns a boolean value. Can you check that client.set(..) is actually returning true ?

Comment: How are you starting `memcached`? Is this code running in the same container as `memcached`?